# applying a where to users relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

i have this line

```
return User::with('image')->with('profile')->paginate(30);
```

which grabs all the users with there image data and profile data, however i cant seem to find a way to apply a where clause to the profile

for instance if i wan't to get all the users, with there image and profile but only if a value in there profile is equal to x
so for example if gender is set to male in there profile i wan't to grab them

how can i do this without grabbing everybody regardless of what a value is in the profile relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the whereHas method:

```
return User::with('image', 'profile')->whereHas('profile', function ($query) {
    $query->where('gender', 'male');
})->get();
```